# Delete lines that do not include only chars

Tags: regex, text, vim

I am trying to delete lines that contains anything else apart from characters of the alphabet and withe-spaces. Numbers, commas, quotes, math symbols: any line with them has to be removed.

Input:

```
FISIOLOGIA UMANA
FISIOLOGIA UMANA
http://id.loc.gov/vocabulary/subjectSchemes/FI
Sepúlveda, Luis
La sirenetta Walt Disney
La sirenetta
CFIV007842
CFIV006619
Lubac, Henri : de
Roma
```

Expected output:

```
FISIOLOGIA UMANA
FISIOLOGIA UMANA
La sirenetta Walt Disney
La sirenetta
Roma
```

So far, I used `:%g!:[A-Za-z]:d` with `Vim`, that was supposed to do the trick. Curiously, it states that it matches every line (as expected) but it does not delete lines where non alphabetic chars are found. What is the reason behind such behavior? How could the issue be smartly approached?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex matches all lines. You need one that checks that there are only characters on the *entire* line:

```
:%g!:^[A-Za-z ]\+$:d
```

Note also that I included the space character since you seem to want to allow that too.

Answer (score 5):

`:%g!:[A-Za-z]:d` is checking to see what lines match the alphabet and then delete the non-matching lines. Since every line matches then no lines will be deleted.

I think it would be easier to search for characters that you want to delete:

```
:g/[^a-zA-Z ]/d_
```

Comment: What is the difference between `d` and `d_`?

Comment: `:d` will delete into a register. By default this is the unnamed register. `:%d_` will delete into the blackhole register which means the deleted text will not alter any other registers. See `:h registers` & `:h quote_`